# how to get twitter feeds from my account?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, twitter

I am developing an app that shows twitter feeds from my account  . I integrate twitter for posting data,image or any link.I searched in google for getting feeds....
Please give any idea .Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can fetch tweets of specific user using below link:

https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=username&count=25&page=1

A good tutorial is http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-json-twitter-api/

Answer (score 0):

Twitter API is available after iOS5.

You an get all information about that in here

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios

If you are searching for getting users timeline feeds. Here it is

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/making-api-requests-twrequest